# Powershell Select-String not finding what I expect

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am trying to parse file paths to just get the file name and I have a regex .*\

I'll use the following

```
Select-String -Pattern '.*\\' -InputObject $test -NotMatch
```

on a file path like C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.exe and it returns blank. If I remove the -NotMatch flag it returns the entire path. I tried using a regex tester so I know the regex is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Select-String`, use `Split-Path -leaf`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like -notmatch just ignores the whole line if there's a match.  How about this?  This is any number of characters that are not backslashes at the end of a line.

```
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.exe' | select-string [^\\]*$ | % matches | % value

test.exe
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. I thought it would return everything but the matching. What do the | and %s mean in your response?

Comment: It's the same thing as `| foreach-object propertyname`, it has the same effect as `| select -expand propertyname`.